# How to get all the Test Case ID using User Story ID of Rally using API request

Tags: api, automation, rally

Hi all I am creating a code where on entering a user story ID it will pass or fail all the TC's of the same using Java. But I cannot quite figure out how to approach and how to get the list of TC ID's from User Story ID. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want to be using the [Rally REST Toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava). Take a look at the ReadMe, you'll find links to the user guide, javadocs and examples there. Find an example that looks similar to what you want to achieve and start working on a solution.

At a high level, you'll want to first load the user story that fits the ID. Then from there you'll be able to load the collection of Test Cases associated with it. The [Rally Web Services API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) will help you understand the story to test case relationship for querying.